# How to make sense of "ever underneath"

Tags: sentence-meaning

Does this sentence:

> He looked shabby, though he was just as a good man as ever underneath.

make sense? I can't clearly understand the part that says "ever underneath". Could you teach me?

Comment: You're parsing it slightly incorrectly.  It's not "(as good a man as) (ever underneath)", it's "he was just as good a man (as ever) (underneath)."  *As ever* means "in the same way that it has always been".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sentence is worded a little oddly.

"He looked shabby, though he was as good a man as ever, underneath." is how I would phrase it.

On the surface he looks shabby. But underneath that shabbyness there is a good man.

Does that make is clearer?

Comment: Does the word "underneath" mean "at one's core"? Does the sentence mean "He has ever be good man at his core though he looked shabby."?

Comment: It technically mean "at the core" but "under something". I.e The dog lay underneath the chair."

However the sentence above is being a little poetic, so you could rewrite it to say "He looked shabby, though he was as good a man as ever, at his core." and retain the same meaning.